# RFID-RC522 not reading card

Tags: arduino, rfid

I have a RFID-RC522 (MF-RC522) module and I'm using Arduino sketch program. I have downloaded the Example code:

```
/*
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 * Example sketch/program showing how to read data from a PICC to serial.
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 * This is a MFRC522 library example; for further details and other examples see: https://github.com/miguelbalboa/rfid
 * 
 * Example sketch/program showing how to read data from a PICC (that is: a RFID Tag or Card) using a MFRC522 based RFID
 * Reader on the Arduino SPI interface.
 * 
 * When the Arduino and the MFRC522 module are connected (see the pin layout below), load this sketch into Arduino IDE
 * then verify/compile and upload it. To see the output: use Tools, Serial Monitor of the IDE (hit Ctrl+Shft+M). When
 * you present a PICC (that is: a RFID Tag or Card) at reading distance of the MFRC522 Reader/PCD, the serial output
 * will show the ID/UID, type and any data blocks it can read. Note: you may see "Timeout in communication" messages
 * when removing the PICC from reading distance too early.
 * 
 * If your reader supports it, this sketch/program will read all the PICCs presented (that is: multiple tag reading).
 * So if you stack two or more PICCs on top of each other and present them to the reader, it will first output all
 * details of the first and then the next PICC. Note that this may take some time as all data blocks are dumped, so
 * keep the PICCs at reading distance until complete.
 * 
 * @license Released into the public domain.
 * 
 * Typical pin layout used:
 * -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 *             MFRC522      Arduino       Arduino   Arduino    Arduino          Arduino
 *             Reader/PCD   Uno/101       Mega      Nano v3    Leonardo/Micro   Pro Micro
 * Signal      Pin          Pin           Pin       Pin        Pin              Pin
 * -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 * RST/Reset   RST          9             5         D9         RESET/ICSP-5     RST
 * SPI SS      SDA(SS)      10            53        D10        10               10
 * SPI MOSI    MOSI         11 / ICSP-4   51        D11        ICSP-4           16
 * SPI MISO    MISO         12 / ICSP-1   50        D12        ICSP-1           14
 * SPI SCK     SCK          13 / ICSP-3   52        D13        ICSP-3           15
 */

#include <SPI.h>
#include <MFRC522.h>

#define RST_PIN         9          // Configurable, see typical pin layout above
#define SS_PIN          10         // Configurable, see typical pin layout above

MFRC522 mfrc522(SS_PIN, RST_PIN);  // Create MFRC522 instance

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);     // Initialize serial communications with the PC
    while (!Serial);        // Do nothing if no serial port is opened (added for Arduinos based on ATMEGA32U4)
    SPI.begin();            // Init SPI bus
    mfrc522.PCD_Init();     // Init MFRC522
    mfrc522.PCD_DumpVersionToSerial();  // Show details of PCD - MFRC522 Card Reader details
    Serial.println(F("Scan PICC to see UID, SAK, type, and data blocks..."));
}

void loop() {
    // Look for new cards
    if ( ! mfrc522.PICC_IsNewCardPresent()) {
        return;
    }

    // Select one of the cards
    if ( ! mfrc522.PICC_ReadCardSerial()) {
        return;
    }

    // Dump debug info about the card; PICC_HaltA() is automatically called
    mfrc522.PICC_DumpToSerial(&(mfrc522.uid));
}
```

When I execute it, I get the message:

Firmware Version: 0x0 = (unknown)

WARNING: Communication failure, is the MFRC522 properly connected?

Scan PICC to see UID, SAK, type, and data blocks...

I have re-checked the connections a thousand time but it's not working, the pins are connected as the example says to, and the LED D1 is on (red). Does anyone can help me?

Comment: Which Arduino are using?

Comment: I have uno and Mega. Both dont work

Comment: You're sure the SS pin is into SDA?

Comment: I have followed those numbers above. So they are as follows: RST ->9, SDA ->10, MOSI -> 11, MISO -> 12, SCK -> 13

Comment: Well this all looks right.   And you have 3.3v and ground wired too correct?

Comment: Yes both are correct

Comment: It's gotta be a bad RFID unit then.

Comment: Did you get it working?

Comment: Yes, but it has been 2 years, I can't remember exactly what I did =/

Answer (score 3):

If anybody looking for a solution...
Step-1: Change the RST pin to 5 if you are using Arduino Uno or use RST pin 9 in Arduino Mega. the other pins remains the same.
Step-2:Download [AddicoreRFID](https://www.addicore.com/v/vspfiles/downloadables/Product%20Downloadables/RFID_RC522/AddicoreRFID.zip) library.
Step-3: Open the Arduino IDE and navigate to Sketch > Include the  Library using  “Add .ZIP Library…” option.
Step-4: Restart the Arduino IDE (close and open again)
Step-5: Inside Arduino IDE Navigate to File > Examples > AddicoreRFID. Select the “Addicore_RFID_Example” sketch and upload the sketch
Step-6: Open the Serial window and select "Both NL & CR" and select "9600" for the baud rate option

**Detail explanation can be found at [link](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/content_link/mExiMCuwHS3rzGm0hpZwKuOHXXXfY1YZ8tyhsHNH1UtAerqx8JUy5cu0d7BuqeGr/file)**

Answer (score 0):

This issue is due to incorrect wiring or loose contacts to RFID sensor. You need to solder contact to get results.

Also, choose appropriate PINS for your Arduino board.

Answer (score 0):

UNO solution worked with me

- Reset Bin is 5 not 10
- Use 5V not 3.3v

[Arduino forum Solution with explanation](https://forum.arduino.cc/t/rc522-not-working/892388/10)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30754952)

Comment: Even though the pin is labeled 3.3V on the board?

Comment: @LucasC.Feijo  yes, they but half of my boards not starts with 5V.   Better solution is remove LED

Answer (score -2):

Try this code

```cpp
     #include <RFID.h>

    /*
    * Pin layout should be as follows (on Arduino Uno):
    * MOSI: Pin 11 / ICSP-4
    * MISO: Pin 12 / ICSP-1
    * SCK: Pin 13 / ISCP-3
    * SS/SDA: Pin 10
    * RST: Pin 9
    */

    #include <SPI.h>
    #include <RFID.h>

    #define SS_PIN 10
    #define RST_PIN 9

    RFID rfid(SS_PIN,RST_PIN);


    int self = 7;
    int bat = 8; 
    int s = 6;

    int serNum[5];
    int cards[][5] = {
      {42,249,70,213,64}

    };

    bool access = false;

    void setup(){

        Serial.begin(9600);
        SPI.begin();
        rfid.init();

        pinMode(self, OUTPUT);
        pinMode(bat ,OUTPUT);
        pinMode(s,OUTPUT);


        digitalWrite(self, LOW);
        digitalWrite(bat , LOW);

    }

    void loop(){

        if(rfid.isCard()){

            if(rfid.readCardSerial()){
                Serial.print(rfid.serNum[0]);
                Serial.print(" ");
                Serial.print(rfid.serNum[1]);
                Serial.print(" ");
                Serial.print(rfid.serNum[2]);
                Serial.print(" ");
                Serial.print(rfid.serNum[3]);
                Serial.print(" ");
                Serial.print(rfid.serNum[4]);
                Serial.println("");

                for(int x = 0; x < sizeof(cards); x++){
                  for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(rfid.serNum); i++ ){
                      if(rfid.serNum[i] != cards[x][i]) {
                          access = false;
                          break;
                      } else {
                          access = true;
                      }
                  }
                  if(access) break;
                }

            }

           if(access){
              Serial.println("Welcome!");
              digitalWrite(bat,HIGH);
              digitalWrite(self,HIGH);
              delay(1000);
              digitalWrite(self,LOW);

          } else {
               Serial.println("Not allowed!");
              digitalWrite(s,HIGH);
              delay(2000);
              digitalWrite(s,LOW); 
              digitalWrite(bat,LOW);

           }        
        }



        rfid.halt();`enter code here`

    }
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, including an explanation [really helps](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.